# Estimated roadmap for Windows support

Tags: windows

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I have a question regarding the estimate  on when Gazebo will support Windows operating system.
I read in the Roadmap page in the wiki ( http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Roadmap ) that Windows support is expected for September 2014. Is this forecast still valid?

Thank you very much in advance for the answer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5270/estimated-roadmap-for-windows-support/) by [silvio.traversaro](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/455/silvio.traversaro/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 200 on 2014-01-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Although the multiplatform support has improved during the last months, after getting sdformat and gazebo to compile and run in MacOsX, which should benefit the Windows compilation, the works for getting gazebo to compile into Windows are yet to start.

I can not speak about the estimated time, but indeed, a port to Windows is on the table for gazebo development team.

**Update as of 23 July:**

[Gazebo 5.0](http://www.gazebosim.org/#status) is the target for having something working on Windows. It is a reference, it could be postponed.

On the windows front, there has been some major improvements in the last months, [like porting sdformat to windows](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/pull-request/101/port-sdformat-to-compile-on-windows-msvc) and [have a continuous job integration for it](http://build.osrfoundation.org/job/sdformat-default-devel-windows7/).

Some more works are in progress and the gazebo math layer and gazebo transport layer are close to start working on Windows. Still very far from having something working, but there is development done in this line.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2014-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silvio.traversaro](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/455/silvio.traversaro/) on 2014-08-15**:
Thanks a lot. I started to look into compiling SDFormat for Windows, from the Jenkins build I guess you are targeting/supporting only Visual Studio 2013 (or newer)?

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-08-15**:
I don't have an strong opinion about which VS version to use but yes, we need something with c++11 support (not for sdformat but some others).

**Comment by [silvio.traversaro](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/455/silvio.traversaro/) on 2014-08-15**:
I guess then VS2013 is the way to go, C++11 support in Visual Studio is still not complete but VS2013 improved the situation. For giving an example, SDFormat is not compiling on VS2012 because the isfinite C++11 function is missing.